# Install package with PyCharm from password-protected repository

Tags: pip, pycharm, python-wheel

I have a password-protected repository that includes a python package with a wheel file. I would like to install it using PyCharm's package manager. If I go to `PyCharm > Preferences > Project > Project Interpreter > + > Manage Repositories > +` I can add a new repository. But if I add a password protected one, nothing appears, which makes sense because there's no way to input the password.

Is there a way to install a python package from a password-protected repository using PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such an ability. Feel free to create a feature-request in the [tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).